# How to insert Semantic UI content into website (using inspector) for UI/UX demo?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, semantic-ui, inspector

I'm building an browser extension that provides extra functionality when posting on Facebook and Twitter. To demo the UI/UX, I'd like to insert content using the inspector so that it looks like it will once it's built. I know how to do this for basic HTML, but when I try to do so with a front-end framework like Semantic UI, I can't get it to work. I included the CDN CSS and JS files, so I figured it would work, but it's not. Does anyone know how to do this?

As an example of what I'd like to include, you can look at the documentation for any of the Semantic UI dropdowns [here](https://semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown.html).

Thank you!

Comment: Can you provide some of your relevant code?

Answer (score 0):

Unless the css, Semantic UI etc is loaded before you edit the page via the editor then it will not work.

As adding the css within the inspector does nothing, the css etc need to load for the browser to register the css/js etc

So make sure the css and js files you need are loaded first.

If your looking to demo html etc why not try some thign like codepen https://codepen.io/

Comment: The trouble is, I want the demo to look and feel just like Facebook/Twitter but with small changes, so I don't think codepen will do the trick. Can I make the css/js load first using inspector?

Comment: no you would need to have the page load it for any effect of adding html element to via the inspector to take effect.